# Error for getters and setters

Tags: c++, vector, getter-setter

I have a vector of vertices and I wish to set vertice.setVisit as false or 0 initially. I defined some getters and setters for this, but getting some type error. Code is as per below:

```
//Vector:
std::vector<project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>*> Vertice1;

//Class containing methods:
template <class VertexType, class EdgeType> class Vertex{
protected:
    //std::vector<std::pair<int, EdgeType>> VertexList;
    VertexType vertice;
    EdgeType edge;
    int num;
    int mark;
    //int status=0;

public:

    void setNum(int){ this.num = num; }
    int getNum() { return num; }
    int getMark(){ return mark; }
    void setVisit(int) { this.mark = mark; }
};
```

In some function I am assigning the values to it as :

```
for(int i=0; i<g1.Vertice1.size(); i++)
{
    g1.Vertice1.at(i)->setNum(0);
    g1.Vertice1.at(i)->setVisit(0);
}
```

Below is the error I am getting while compilation of the code for "this.mark=mark" and for "this.num=num" in the function definition in class.

```
Error: left of '.mark' must have class/struct/union
 Error: left of '.num' must have class/struct/union
```

Isn't this the correct way to assign the values through getter and setters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer-type. Try `this->mark` or `(*this).mark`

**EDIT:** As Richard pointed out below, also be sure to name your parameters which you are trying to assign. In context, `this->mark = mark` is the same thing as `this->mark = this->mark`. Unless `mark` is a parameter, `this` is really unnecessary in this case. So realistically, you can get rid of `this` all together in your example by doing something like this:

```
void setVisit(int newMark) { mark = newMark; }
```

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: Ohhh cool.... it worked. Actually in Java it goes like this.mark=mark and hence was trying that. Thanks anyways for providing quick solution :)

Comment: No problem! I appended the answer a little bit with just a bit more information. Good luck!

Comment: @tech_learning : That would work here as well (of course with 'this->` rather than `this.`) if you had given the member function parameter name `mark`. But, you left the parameter unnamed.

Comment: Ohh ok... wasn't aware of that. Thanks anyways to All and Good Luck... :D

Answer (score 3):

Change setNum and setVisit to the following

```
void setNum(int num) {this->num = num; }
void setVisit(int mark) {this->mark = mark; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer, so you have to use `this->num`.